# Update database under replication

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, replication

I'm trying to import data from production database to my test database to have the same data.
I've export all insert statements with SSMS Tools. This insert contains "rowguid" from replication.

But when I'm trying to insert the data -> I've got a message like this :
"The INSERT Statements failed, because it was in conflict with the verification ID constraint in the database XXX, replicated table YYY, colum ZZZ. If the column ID is auto generated by the replication, please update it like this : Publication server, execute sp_adjustpublisheridentityrange / For Subscriber, Execute distribution Agent or Fusion Agent"

But I don't know how. Someone can explain it to me ?

Comment: Can you post one line of the insert statement ? Also is the schema the same on both production database and test database?